# How to deal with large Excel file using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to deal with an Excel file which comprises 1 million rows. However, when I open it in MATLAB, only 10,000 rows are displayed.... Could anyone tell me how to import full data using MATLAB?

Comment: How are you currently trying to import it? What does it contain? (how many columns, is all content numerical or is it mixed).

Comment: Please show what you did and what exactly is the result. This is way to vague for directed advice. In general `xlsread`, or 'rightclick' and 'import' should get you what you want. There is no 10000 line limit for importing into matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type at your MATLAB Command Window:

```
[~,~,data] = xlsread('X:\path to your file\excel file.xls');
```

where you should replace the `xlsread` argument with something that's suitable. The result will be a cell array of mixed numeric (if they could be converted) and strings read from the first sheet in the file. First cell in `data` corresponds to the upper/left cell in the worksheet.

If you want to specify the sheet, or for more refined function call, read [the function's help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html).

**NB**

Some of the ways to call the `xlsread` function are possible or not depending on whether you have Office installed or not.